# Why is process.stdout.write() is adding an extra 0 to squared result?

Tags: javascript

I am simply trying to square a number by passing in a number using process.stdin and then using process.stdout.write.

I first attempted this:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    stdin += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    var lines = stdin.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        let num = Number(lines[i])
        let sqrd = num*num
        process.stdout.write(sqrd);
    }
});
```

I then get a data type error because I am returning a number and not a string. I then tried the following modification to process.stout.write(sqrd):

```
process.stdout.write(sqrd.toString());
```

I expect if I passed a value 5 that it would return 25, but in actual act it returns 250. Why is this?

Is there a better way to return the result?

EDIT: I have tried finding out the type of the returned value:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    stdin += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
    var lines = stdin.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        let sqrd = lines[i]*lines[i]
        process.stdout.write(typeof(sqrd));
    }
});
```

and it returns "numbernumber" which suggest that it is trying to write it twice??

Comment: Maybe your `stdin` encountered a `0` *after* `5` and when both squared, the output came as `250`

Comment: @rv7 I am being passed a positive integer, so I am not sure how I would encounter a 0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second iteration is caused by the New Line (\n) character remaining in your array of lines. Don't iterate over the last element. To fix this do:

**Change:**

`for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {`

**To:**

`for(var i=0; i<lines.length - 1; i++) {`